# Altium Designer - fabrication output out of scale

Tags: altium

I'm trying to make circuit board using thermal transfer method. When I done with drawing pcb board in project, I saved it as fabrication output (previously setting scale 1.00 in Page Setup), and printed it (also in scale 100%). When I checked the size of tracks and pads, I noticed it's different than on the pcb project. Photos: (don't mind about green colour, it's for my personal use and I really didn't care about rules).

[image: Project, length between pads in milimeters]

[image: Reality. Typical goldpin with contacts pitch 2,54mm]

I'm out of ideas. What could the problem be?

Comment: Is the connector pitch really 2.54mm? ;)

Comment: Did you export the file to PDF or print directly from altium? If you used a PDF your PDF reader might have rescaled the file before printing.

Comment: Rev1.0, yes - I checked it twice on prototype board with 2,54mm pitch.
Andreas Wallaner - I exported it to PDF, and then printed. I don't have printer on my own, but I printed it on two different printers, and result was the same.

I think I found soultion, but at first I need to check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, step after step what I did to receive properly print (I don't know exactly what helped)
 1. Choose .PcbDoc file with drawn PCB. Press File->Page Setup, set scale to 1.00 and press close.
 2. Still in the same file press File->SmartPDF, and only make sure that setting will be saved to Output Job document.
 3. Open this Output Job document, you can delete Documentation Output and add Fabriaction Output (Final Artwork Prints). Press right mouse button -> Page Setup, and set scale to 1.00
 4. Choose PDF output container and generate content.

After that, you can double check measurment in Adobe Reader selecting Edit->Analysis->Measuring Tools.